# Prove that two processes have the same law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_t=A\cos(\alpha t)+B\sin(\alpha t)$ and $Y_t=R\cos(\alpha t+\Theta)$, where $\alpha>0$, $A$ and $B$ are independent random variables with distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$, and $R$ and $\Theta$ are also independent random variables with $\Theta\sim U(0,2\pi)$ and $R$ with density $$f_R(r)=\frac{x}{\sigma^2}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right){1}_{(0,\infty)}(x).$$
Prove that the processes $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$ and $\{Y_t\}_{t\geq0}$ have the same law.

My attempt: Fixed $\omega$, we have that $A(\omega)=\rho(\omega)\cos\eta(\omega)$ and $B(\omega)=-\rho(\omega)\sin\eta(\omega)$, where $\rho(\omega)=\sqrt{A(\omega)^2+B(\omega)^2}$ and $\eta(\omega)\in [0,2\pi]$. Let us study the behaviour of $\rho$ and $\eta$. For $\rho$, $$P(\rho\leq z)=P(A^2+B^2\leq z^2)=P\left(\left(\frac{A}{\sigma}\right)^2+\left(\frac{B}{\sigma}\right)^2\leq\frac{z^2}{\sigma^2}\right).$$ As $A/\sigma,B/\sigma\sim N(0,1)$, we have $(A/\sigma)^2+(B/\sigma)^2\sim\chi^2(2)$, therefore $$P(\rho\leq z)=F_{\chi^2(2)}(z^2/\sigma^2)=\int_0^{z^2/\sigma^2}\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}e^{-t/2}}_{\text{density } \chi^2(2)}\,dt=1-e^{-z^2/(2\sigma^2)}.$$
Differentiating, $$f_{\rho}(z)=\frac{z}{\sigma^2}\text{exp}(-z^2/(2\sigma^2))1_{(0,\infty)}(z),$$
so $\rho\stackrel{d}{=}R$ ...

My questions:

1. How can I prove that $\eta\sim U(0,2\pi)$?
2. How can I know that $\rho$ and $\eta$ are independent?
3. Does this help me to finish the exercise?

Comment: To answer all your three items at once, compute the joint distribution of $(\rho,\eta)$, using the change of variable formula for the transformation $g:(0,\infty)\times(\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z)\to\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ defined by $$g:(r,t)\mapsto(r\cos t,r\sin t)$$ You should reach the density $$f_\rho(r)f_\eta(t)$$ for some simple $f_\theta$, simultaneously proving independence and identifying the distribution of $\eta$.

Comment: @Did Ok, I have proved that $$f_{\rho,\eta}(r,t)=f_{A,B}(r\cos t,r\sin t)r=\frac{r}{2\pi\sigma^2}e^{-r^2/(2\sigma^2)}\cdot 1_{(0,\infty)\times (0,2\pi)}(r,t).$$ From here, how do I conclude that $$f_{\rho}(r)=\frac{r}{\sigma^2}e^{-r^2/(2\sigma^2)}\cdot 1_{(0,\infty)}(r)$$ and $f_{\eta}(t)=1/(2\pi)\cdot 1_{[0,2\pi]}$?

Comment: By identifying PDFs $g$ and $h$ such that $$f_{\rho,\eta}(r,t)=g(r)h(t)$$ then you are sure that $$f_\rho=g\qquad f_\eta=h\qquad f_{\rho,\eta}(r,t)=f_\rho(r)f_\eta(t)$$ that is, everything you need. In general, more complicated, not necessarily independent, cases, you would compute the marginal distributions from the joint distribution through *marginalization*, for example, $$f_\rho(r)=\int f_{\rho,\eta}(r,t)dt$$

Comment: @Did Ok, so I have now that $\rho\stackrel{d}{=}R$ and $\eta\stackrel{d}{=}\Theta$, and $\rho$ and $\eta$ independent. Can I conclude from here that $$ P(R\cos(\alpha t+\Theta)\leq a)=P(\rho\cos(\alpha t+\eta)\leq a) $$ for all $a$?

Comment: Sure, since, for some given $g$ and $\alpha$, $P(g(U,V)\leqslant\alpha)$ is the same for every $(U,V)$ that has some given joint distribution.